# No CUDA runtime is found, using CUDA_HOME='C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.2'

Tags: python, windows, pytorch, nvidia

I have downloaded versions 12 for both CUDA Tookkit and CUDNN 
I have already installed the latest PyTorch 2.0.0,
`pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu117` 
with CUDA 11.7 version to be exact as it was the one available.

Please let me know how I can solve the issue as I get the 'No CUDA runtime is found, using 
`CUDA_HOME='C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.2`
error everytime. 
The path stated should have the runtime as I downloaded the runtime and everything else from the CUDA installer into that path.

Comment: If your Pytorch is demanding a CUDA tookit, the it will have to be the version it was built with, i.e. CUDA 11.7